# How to count occurrences of a key-value pair per individual object in JQ?

Tags: json, group-by, count, jq

I could not find how to count occurrence of "title" grouped by "member_id"...
The json file is:

```
[
 {
  "member_id": 123,
  "loans":[
   {
    "date": "123",
    "media": [
     { "title": "foo" },
     { "title": "bar" }
    ]
   },
   {
    "date": "456",
    "media": [
     { "title": "foo" }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "member_id": 456,
  "loans":[
   {
    "date": "789",
    "media": [
     { "title": "foo"}
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

With this query I get loan entries for users with "title==foo"

```
 jq '.[] | (.member_id) as $m | .loans[].media[] | select(.title=="foo") | {id: $m, title: .title}' member.json
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "foo"
}
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "foo"
}
{
  "id": 456,
  "title": "foo"
}
```

But I could not find how to get count by user (*group by*) for a title, to get a result like:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "foo",
  "count": 2
}
{
  "id": 456,
  "title": "foo",
  "count": 1
}
```

I got errors like `jq: error (at member.json:31): object ({"title":"f...) and array ([[123]]) cannot be sorted, as they are not both arrays` or similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using group_by :

```
jq  'map(
         (.member_id) as $m
        | .loans[].media[]
        | select(.title=="foo")
        | {id: $m, title: .title}
        )
    |group_by(.id)[]
    |.[0] + { count: length }
' input-file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Philippe, I missed the `.[0] + {}`

Answer (score 3):

1. When the main goal is to count, it is usually more efficient to avoid constructing an array if determining its length is the only reason for doing so.  In the present case you could, for example, write:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (null; .+1);

"foo" as $title | .[] | {
  id: .member_id,
  $title,
  count: count(.loans[].media[] | select(.title == $title))
}
```

2. `group_by` has its uses, but it is well to be aware that it is  inefficient even for grouping, because its implementation involves a sort, which is not strictly necessary if the goal is to "group by" some criterion.  A completely generic sort-free "group by" function is a bit tricky to implement, but often a simple but non-generic version is sufficient, such as:

```
# sort-free variant of group_by/1
# f must always evaluate to an integer or always to a string, which
# could be achieved by using `tostring`.
# Output: an array in the former case, or an object in the latter case
def GROUP_BY(f): reduce .[] as $x (null; .[$x|f] += [$x] );
```